# Como guardar los valores de un array de objectos

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo un array de objetos, que tiene las llaves `material, codigoMontado, codigoDesmonte` de esta forma:

```
Array = [
{codigoDesmonte: "12345678"
codigoMontado: "2345678"
material: "METAL"},
{
codigoDesmonte: "12345678"
codigoMontado: "23456789"
material: "PLASTICO"
},
{
codigoDesmonte: "3e4e5678"
codigoMontado: "345678"
material: "MADERA"}
]
```

Como puedo guardar en tres arrays diferentes cada uno de los valores dependiendo la llave, es decir, solo los valores del material de esta forma:

```
materialesArray = ["METAL","PLASTICO","MADERA"];
codigoDesmonteArray = ["12345678","12345678","3e4e5678"];
codigoMontadoArray = [2345678,23456789,345678];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo usando [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach), en los comentarios tienes una breve explicación de lo que hago, para más detalle visita el enlace anterior que lleva a la documentación.

```js
//Creo los arrays que guardarán los datos por separado
let codigosDesmonte = [];
let codigosMontado = [];
let materiales = [];

let arr = [
{codigoDesmonte: "12345678",
codigoMontado: "2345678",
material: "METAL"},
{
codigoDesmonte: "12345678",
codigoMontado: "23456789",
material: "PLASTICO"
},
{
codigoDesmonte: "3e4e5678",
codigoMontado: "345678",
material: "MADERA"}
]

//Recorro el array elemento a elemento con forEach:
arr.forEach(element => {
  //Añado a cada array su valor
   codigosDesmonte.push(element.codigoDesmonte);
   codigosMontado.push(element.codigoMontado);
   materiales.push(element.material);
});
//Verifico que todo está bien
console.log("Codigos desmonte:");
console.log(codigosDesmonte);
console.log("Codigos montaje:");
console.log(codigosMontado);
console.log("Materiales:");
console.log(materiales);
```